# Should I commit before merging tag to branch?

Tags: git, merge, commit

Should I commit before merging a tag to branch?

I have some staged files ready to commit.

on branch "branch1" created from version 1.0

```
  foo.html
  bar.js
  hello.java
```

Now need to merge tag version 5.0 to the branch.

Should commit the staged files first before merging?

If merge without commit first, and
If there is conflict for the file hello.java, how it will be resolved? all merged files are in working directory (not staged)?

Comment: You *must* commit before running `git merge`. Otherwise `git merge` will tell you that you're not yet ready to merge, because you have uncommitted work, and will refuse to run. (Caveat: this is true for the *user oriented* `git merge` command, but *not* true for the individual back-end merge implementations. Do not use them directly unless you already know the answer to the question you asked here.) Note that this has nothing to do with Git*Hub* at all, it's just basic command-line Git.

Comment: Besides the above, note that you don't actually merge a *tag* or a *branch*. What you really merge is a *commit*. You can provide a tag name (less typical) or branch name (much more typical) *to* the `git merge` command; Git will locate the commit using the name you provided.